# Scriptural reference for Navadurga

Tags: puranas, tantra, festivals, durga, nava-durga

*Navarātri* is popularly considered to be 9 days dedicated to the worship of *Navadurgā* i.e 9 forms of Bhagavatī Durgā. However the *Devi-Bhāgavata Purāna*, which describes the procedure of *Navarātri vrata*, has no mention of *Navadurgā*. The only mention of *Navadurgā* found till now is in the *Kālikā Purāna* where they are simply described as *āvaraṇa devatā*s of *Kāmakhyā* while being worshipped in the sacred *Yonimaṇḍala* of *Kāmarūpa* but nothing about their iconography or association with *Navarātri*. So can anybody cite any valid scriptural reference for *Navadurgā* worship during *Navaratri* ?

Answer (score 4):

Durga saptshati has multiple mentions of Navdurga.

When Markandeya ji asks for Durga kavach mantra, Brahma ji describes nine form of Durga or Navdurga.

1. Shailputri / Parvati : fear and sorrow goes away by her darshan. Daughter of Himalaya.

> [image: Navdurga]

2. Brahmacharini : who continuously seeks Brahma
3. Chandraghanta : Moon resides in who's Ghanta
4. Kushmanda : this warm Universe resides in who's abdomen
5. Skandamata : mother of Skanda
6. Katyayani : daughter of Rishi Katya
7. Kaalratri : destroyer of Kaal(death)
8. Mahagauri : who received great Gaur varna by tapasya
9. Siddhidatri : who gives Moksha

> [image: Navdurga]

Comment: which scripture contains Durga Kavacha? It is not present in Saptashati (Markandeya Purana)...

Comment: @Tezz Devi Kavacha is always recited along with Chandi Patha. Its a limb of the whole recital. So I always assumed that it is also from the same Purana which has Devi Mahatyam but may be its from another scripture.

Comment: [This page](https://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/durga-saptashati/patha-vidhi/devi-kavacham/durga-saptashati-devi-kavacham.html) says that Devi Kavacha is the Beejam for Durga Saptasati. Anyway its mandatory to recite Argala, Kavacha etc. before reciting the Chandi.

Comment: Still this doesn't answers the question of how do we came to know about the iconography of Navadurga & why they are specifically associated with Sharad Navaratri & not any other day.

Comment: @Tezz Durga Saptshati published by Gita Press has chapter "अथ देव्याः कवचम्" has these shlokas. The original source is not mentioned in the book. Maybe I will write to Gita press and request for the info.

Comment: Swami Sivananda's translation says devi kavach is part of markandeya purana

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is the connection between Navadurgas and Navratri. This is an interesting question.

However, Navadurgas are not only mentioned in Kalika Purana. They are also mentioned in the Skanda Purana. After Sati's death, they were sent along with Virabhadra, Bhutas, Ganas, Yoginis etc.

> Expressly commanded by Rudra himself the extremely powerful Vīrabhadra came to the sacrificial enclosure **accompanied by the nine Durgās and others. The nine Durgās were Kālī, Kātyāyanī, Īśānā, Cāmuṇḍā, Muṇḍamardinī, Bhadrakālī, Bhadrā, Tvaritā and Vaiṣṇavī.** A big multitude of Bhūtas also entered the sacrificial enclosure of great refulgence. Śākinīs, Ḍākinīs, Bhūtas, Pramathas, Guhyakas, a host of Yoginīs (in circular formation) along with the sixty-four (Tantras) — all these entered the sacrificial enclosure suddenly. *- Skanda Purana I.1.3.49-51*

Reference -

1. [The Skanda Purana by G V Tagare, 1950](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc365950.html)